# Classification of homotopy types of topological spaces

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory

Do higher groups classify the homotopy types of topological spaces?
We may assume $\pi_n$ of the topological spaces are all finite
and $\pi_n =0$ for large enough $n$.

For example, if only $\pi_1 \neq 0$ and finite, the
homotopy types of topological spaces are classified by finite groups.

Added: the term "higher group" refers to the higher group defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-group_(category_theory)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It appears that the finiteness of $\pi_n$ is important.

Comment: I think at most only the weak homotopy type can be determined, even in the $\pi_1$ case.

Comment: Look up "Postnikov tower" and "k-invariants"

Comment: Do higher groups classify the weak homotopy types of topological spaces, for finite $\pi_n$ which are non-zero only for small enough $n$?

Comment: No, if this were true than all spaces would be weakly equivalent to a product of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces. Explicitly, an example of such a space can be obtained by taking the mapping cone for any cohomology operation of degree higher than 1. This will have two non-trivial homotopy groups, but is not a product of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces, as you can detect by using the cohomology operation used to generate the space.

Comment: I think there is a miscommunication here. I believe the OP means "higher groups" in the sense of 2-groups etc - i.e. group objects in a homotopical context, NOT  just the graded group given by the collection of homotopy groups. In this case the answer is I believe tautologically yes for connected spaces -- there's an equivalence of (oo-)categories between n-truncated connected pointed spaces (pi-finite) and n-groups given by taking loops / taking classifying spaces.

Comment: David Ben-Zvi
Thanks. I did not realize that "higher group" is not a standard term in mathematics. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen a very common situation in mathematics is that terms aren't so much underdefined, but that they are overdefined (there are different notions sharing the same name). In this case, 'higher' could refer to $\pi_2,\pi_3$ etcetera, or additional structure on the group(oid).

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen I think the terminology "higher groups" is unambiguous, but familiar only to a relatively small community. In this general context people jumped to the conclusion you didn't mean them in the precise sense but rather meant "higher homotopy groups".

Comment: Good catch, @DavidBen-Zvi!

Comment: The answer is supposed to be yes, @Xiao-GangWen (with a small adjustment about $\pi_0$): if a space has $\pi_k(X, x_0)=0$ for all $k>n$ and all $x_0 \in X$, then the homotopy type should be determined by the fundamental $n$-groupoid of $X$. If $\pi_0(X)=pt$, then this $n$-groupoid is an $n$-group. The difficulty is proving these claims for a given definition of $n$-group. There are definitions for which it can be proved, but those don't make $n$-groups feel very algebraic, and there are some more algebraic definitions of $n$-group for which this result can only be proved for small $n$.

Comment: The questions is closely related to the "Homotopy Hypothesis", https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+hypothesis